# JNDI creation in Apache Tomcat 7 using context.xml of application

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I am trying to create a test application for JNDI with below code along with a test servlet to verify if the connection is established successfully. I didn't make any configuration settings on **server.xml** and **context.xml** assuming I don't have to do them when I configure with context.xml in META-INF of application

However, I always get the error "**Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null**' "

I searched old issues, and most of the issues of similar error messages were caused by mistaken JDBC URL. But in my case I don't think it's a problem with JDBC URL. 
The print stacktrace shows:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
>     ... 43 more

I even tried with MySQL jar file on lib directory of Tomcat; it's still the same. 
Full stacktrace as below:

> INFO: Server startup in 1116 ms
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC
>   driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.angelfrend.samples.StandaloneJNDI.dao.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:45)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
>     ... 43 more

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.samples.dao</groupId>
  <artifactId>StandaloneJNDI</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>StandaloneJNDI Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>StandaloneJNDI</finalName>
  </build>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
      version="2.4">
  <display-name>Servlet 2.4 Web Application</display-name>
  <description>MySQL Test</description>  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.samples.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>   
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  
  </resource-ref>
```

context.xml ( placed in META-INF folder of src/main/resources )

```
<Context>
        <Resource   name="jdbc/TestDB" 
        auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="user" password="pass" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JavaTest" /></Context>
```

Can somebody assist me on how it works?
Can't we create a JNDI connection without configuring server.xml or context.xml ??

Comment: Your problem seems to be a little mistake on the resource creation, you did not close the tag `Resource`  `..... :3306/JavaTest" />` see the bar at the end? See if it helps, I will add as an answer if it do.

Comment: ahh !! Thanks for finding it out bro, I will check it :)

Comment: I have missed the /> while formatting here Jorge , I am correcting the pots as well to avoid confusion

Comment: Another thing, This resource file should be on tomcat classhpath, not your project. It should be on `[tomcat_path/conf/Catalina/localhost/nameOfYourApplication.xml]` (production enviroment) or if you are using eclipse it should be on the server.xml file inside the already existing context tag